# How to count number of occurrences of a word in a string using Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

This was my attempt , I wanted to take a window of 3 letters and walk through the string, But not getting the expected answer of 2 . I am getting into some infinite loop. Wondering why .

```
def find_bob(s1):
    check_list = 'bob'
    count = 0
    n=0
    cmp_chars=0
    while n<=len(s1):
        while cmp_chars == s1[n:3]:
            if cmp_chars == check_list:
                count += 1
                continue
    return count

s1= 'azcbobobegghakl'
#check_list='bob'
val1 = find_bob(s1)
```

Comment: you never increment `n` and not really sure what's up with `while cmp_chars == s1[n:3]:`

Comment: @TylerSebastian - trying to see if any 3 letters = 'bob'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Wondering why...`

```
n=0
cmp_chars=0
while n<=len(s1):
    while cmp_chars == s1[n:3]:
        if cmp_chars == check_list:
            count += 1
            continue
```

`n` starts at zero and does not change within the loop so the while condition is always True.

`while cmp_chars == s1[n:3]:` Not sure what to make of this, `cmp_chars` starts at zero and will never equal a string so this loop condition is always False.

Try

```
while n<=len(s1):
    if s1[n:n+3] == check_list:
        count += 1
    n = n +1
```

Comment: This is much more easier to understand  ! Thanks @wwii

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.find()` to find your `bob`s by using the `start` param, e.g.:

```
def find_bob(s):
    check_list = 'bob'
    c, n = 0, s.find(check_list)
    while n != -1:
        c += 1
        n = s.find(check_list, n+1)
    return c

In []:
find_bob('azcbobobegghakl')

Out[]:
2
```

Comment: man, I use Python daily and `c, n = 0, s.find(check_list)` took me a while... Python's nice but it's not always all that clear.

Comment: @TylerSebastian heh, it's just a tuple unpack - you can always split them across 2 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Cli70D/1) with a [zero width lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) and just count the matches:

```
>>> import re
>>> s1= 'azcbobobegghakl'
>>> len([m for m in re.finditer(r'(?=bob)', s1)])
2
```